# How to set a clickable button in a Honeycomb rich notification?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

What's the correct way to set a clickable button in a rich notification in Honeycomb? Like the media play buttons shown here (which I think are from the Music app) -

http://androidcommunity.com/google-details-honeycombs-notification-bar-20110202/

It's not setSmallIcon() in Notification.Builder. That call sets the icon that identifies the app in the status bar.

Looking at Notification.Builder, do we need to call setContent() with a RemoteViews object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct you need to create a [RemoteViews](http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html) object which allows you to specify [PendingIntent](http://d.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)s for individual widgets within  it by calling setOnClickPendingIntent.  You can then set this [RemoteViews](http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html) as the [Notification](http://d.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html)'s [contentView](http://d.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#contentView):

```
RemoteViews layout = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);
notification.contentView = layout;
layout.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_button, getDialogPendingIntent("Tapped the 'dialog' button in the notification."));
```

See the [Honeycomb Gallery](http://d.android.com/resources/samples/HoneycombGallery/src/com/example/android/hcgallery/MainActivity.html) for a full example of this.